# Developer Console | Show Inspector/Elements and Console simultaneously

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

This question targets both, Firefox and Google Chrome. I often need the inspector and the console at the same time, e.g. if I need to try a specific javascript operation with the DOM.

Is it possible to show them simultaneously e.g. side by side?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. You just have to press `ESC`. Works in both browsers.